# Trying to depoloy a Mule pipeline on jenkins but receiving this error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, mule, mulesoft

Jenkins build is giving me the error below:

> Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/ammanbesaw/customer-xapi-app-v1.git
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
> WorkflowScript: 4: unexpected token: Application’ @ line 4, column 14.
> stage(‘Build Application’) {
> ^

1 error

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:349)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:225)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:191)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:189)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:966)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:626)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:677)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:689)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:553)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:505)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:335)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
```

Finished: FAILURE

The below is my Jenkinsfile:

```html
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
stage(‘Build Application’) {
steps {
bat ‘mvn clean install’
}
}
stage(‘Test’) {
steps {
echo ‘Application in Testing Phase…’
bat ‘mvn test’
}
}
stage(‘Deploy CloudHub’) {
environment {
ANYPOINT_CREDENTIALS = credentials(‘anypointPlatform’)
}
steps {
echo ‘Deploying mule project due to the latest code commit…’
echo ‘Deploying to the configured environment….’
bat ‘mvn package deploy -DmuleDeploy -Dusername=${ANYPOINT_CREDENTIALS_USR} -Dpassword=${ANYPOINT_CREDENTIALS_PSW} -DworkerType=Micro -Dworkers=1 -Dregion=us-west-2’
}
}
}
}
```

I'm lost. Any help would really be appreciated

Comment: Seems like the single quotes `'` were somehow replaced with the fancy quotes `‘`. Can you check that in your script. It sometimes happens while copying a text from different editor. Not sure if it is incorrect just here or in your script, can you try to check that.

Comment: change all the single quotes u have used in that script. It works once that is done. Also try to use proper indentations so that you could read and debug the jenkinsfile.

Comment: You were right. Thank you so much. I was going crazy

Comment: @HarshankBansal you should post it as a solution.

Comment: I have put it as an answer, however, the error was a result of a typo, so I thought it might get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the single quotes `'` were somehow replaced with the fancy quotes `‘`. It sometimes happens while copying a text from different editor, like from MS word to Notepad. Replace all the `‘` in your code with `'`.